# How many total members can be divided into 3 parts (in set)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} has several sub-sets whose total members can be divided into 3 parts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Ali. Can you make it more clear what you mean by this division? An example would help.

Comment: Maybe subsets whos "sum" is a multiple of $3$? like $\{ 1,2,3 \}, \{ 6 \}$ and so on

Comment: Mauro ALLEGRANZA.
Yes. It's correct.

Comment: Reading the body of the question, I feel like the only possible answer is "Yes, the set {1,2,3,4,5,6} does have several such sub-sets."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, you are asking how many subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ are such that their subset-sum is a multiple of $3$...?

Notice that the elements $3,6$ are irrelevant here.  They can be added or removed to any such set and not affect whether the subset-sum is a multiple of $3$ or not.

For each other number, it must be paired with another from the opposing remainder-class... so $1$ would need to be paired with a $5$ for instance so that $1+5$ is a multiple of three.

So, either we have exactly one of $\{1,4\}$ and exactly one of $\{2,5\}$ and any number from $\{3,6\}$, or we have exactly two of $\{1,4\}$ and exactly two of $\{2,5\}$ and any number from $\{3,6\}$, or we have none of $\{1,4\},\{2,5\}$ and any number from $\{3,6\}$.

If you include the empty set then in your count, this leaves us with a total of $2\times 2\times 2^2 + 2^2+2^2 = 24$, or if you don't include the empty set, $23$.